# How to find crash issue in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, calayer

I am facing the crash issue in our app in everywhere I am not finding any solutions can you suggest me how to fix the crash issue,  it randomly crashes in the whole app.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: '*** Collection  was mutated while
>   being enumerated.'
>       *** First throw call stack:
>       (0x18ff7efe0 0x18e9e0538 0x18ff7ea30 0x19639c4d4 0x19639c738 0x19639c8c8 0x1004511e0 0x100450b10 0x10063aee8 0x1006336a8
>   0x1005b0b04 0x1005929a0 0x1005ed8b4 0x1017284fc 0x1931905dc
>   0x19319048c 0x1901ebb9c 0x18ff15960 0x18ff2dae4 0x18ff2d284
>   0x18ff2ad98 0x18fe5ada4 0x1918c4074 0x196115058 0x1001886dc
>   0x18ee6959c)
>       libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

```
navView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,70)]; 
[self.view addSubview:navView]; 
[mapView clear]; 
mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,70, self.view.frame.size.width,-70) camera:camera];
 mapView.delegate = self; 
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle]; 
NSURL *styleUrl = [mainBundle URLForResource:@"customMapsJson" withExtension:@"json"]; 
NSError *error; GMSMapStyle *style = [GMSMapStyle styleWithContentsOfFileURL:styleUrl error:&error];
 [self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

Comment: please add some code

Comment: navView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,70)];
    [self.view addSubview:navView];
    [mapView clear];
    mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,70, self.view.frame.size.width,-70) camera:camera];
    mapView.delegate = self;
    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSURL *styleUrl = [mainBundle URLForResource:@"customMapsJson" withExtension:@"json"];
    NSError *error;
    GMSMapStyle *style = [GMSMapStyle   styleWithContentsOfFileURL:styleUrl error:&error];
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];

Comment: @matloob its happening whole app i am not using any extra code.

Comment: then it would be difficult to tell whats happening actually

Comment: Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Comment: And please do not post code in comments. [Edit] your question.

Comment: The error said you changed the Collection when it on enumerated. you need to check all enumerate (such as for-loop) in whole app.

Comment: @MssiOS  can you please edit your question & provide some code. One more option is add exception breakpoint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode

 As a beginner be clear what you want to ask. Post some of your work for better response. Otherwise negative marking, rework :(

Comment: insert overall code ...

Comment: @Gagan our app is crashed randomly any where but i am getting where my app is crashed.

Comment: @MssiOS  ok that's great. May i know the reason & how u find that

Comment: can you post your delegate methods of your `GMSMapView` i think that crash your app.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS i am finding crash every where i am facing same issue

Comment: @MssiOS can you share your code. If possible Via GIT or dropbox etc

Comment: @Gagan here is the my code https://www.dropbox.com/s/2toc01q25au84u7/ListViewController_old.m?dl=0

Comment: @MssiOS Ohh you have added the only .m file. Please provide the complete set for debugging.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS means you need complete code.

Answer (score -1):

To know about random crash, you must have to implement Firebase Crash Analytics. You can check you crash issues with all details over Firebase console.

Please refer below link:-

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/